# Filtrado de fechas en tkinter de python con sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Buen dia amigos!!!!
Nuevamente recurro a ustedes, continuo con mi programa y gracias a la ayuda que he obtenido en este foro he hecho ciertas modificaciones y ajustes en el programa ya que las hice continué con un nuevo reto en donde esta vez quiero hacer un filtrado de fechas en python lo que hice es tomar la fecha con la ayuda de datatime como fecha de estudio (segun ese dia se paga el estudio) y se guarda en la base de datos con ese formato (tipo datetime) la idea es hacer un corte de las ventas de cada mes, y lo que  hice fue usar la sentencia:

```
"SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE fecha_de_estudio BETWEEN 09, Jul, 2019 AND 23, Jul, 2019"
```

En este caso si se hace el filtrado y se obtiene el rango de fechas esperado, entonces coloqué un Entry de Tkinter para hacerlo ya con variables y no logro obtener el resultado esperado

```
Label(self.tab2, text = 'Fecha de inicio: ', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W + E)
self.fecha_inicial = Entry(self.tab2, width = 10)
self.fecha_inicial.focus()
self.fecha_inicial.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10, sticky = W)

Label(self.tab2, text = 'Fecha final: ', bg = 'gray',).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W + E)
self.fecha_final = Entry(self.tab2, width = 10)
self.fecha_final.grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady = 10, sticky = W )

Button(self.tab2, text = 'Seleccionar mes', command = self.get_mes).grid(row = 2, column = 2, pady = 10, padx = 10, sticky = W + E ) 


def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()): 

    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_lab) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
    # Consulta de datos
    query = ("SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE fecha_de_estudio BETWEEN ? AND ?", self.fecha_i.date(), self.fecha_f.date())

    db_rows = self.run_query(query)


def get_mes(self):
    self.fecha_i = datetime.strptime(self.fecha_inicial.get(), '%d, %b, %Y')
    self.fecha_f = datetime.strptime(self.fecha_final.get(), '%d, %b, %Y')    

    records = self.tree2.get_children()

    for element in records:
        self.tree2.delete(element)

    query = ("SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE fecha_de_estudio BETWEEN ? AND ?", self.fecha_i.date(), self.fecha_f.date())

    db_rows = self.run_query(query)

    for row in db_rows:
    self.tree2.insert('', 0, text = row[0], values = (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19]))
```

me pueden apoyar en este problema que tengo por favor, no logro encontrar mi error 
y una pregunta adicional a que se refiere este error: ValueError: operation parameter must be str (me aparecia cuando modificaba la busqueda)

muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Hola Johnny, no veo aparentemente ningún problema siempre y cuando en los Entrys ingreses algo como "15, jul, 2019" y que el mes se ajuste a tu configuración local (español, inglés, etc). El error `ValueError: operation parameter must be str` pasa cuando a `cursor.execute` no  le pasas una cadena como primer argumento (la query). Por ejemplo, si en tu caso haces `cursor.execute(query)`, dado que `query` es una tupla, tendrás el error mencionado. ¿Podrías aclarar que quieres decir con "no logro obtener el resultado esperado"? ¿Tienes algún error? ¿Consulta vacía? ¿Contenido de los Entry?

Comment: No se como haces la consulta en `self.run_query`, pero debe ser algo así: `cursor.execute(query[0], query[1:])`

Comment: Amigo JFSevilla muchas gracias por tu comentario, acabo de poner la consulta que estoy haciendo que segun yo estoy usando, ahhh lo de "resultado esperado" me refiero a que se despliegue en la tabla que la deje en blanco, la idea es colocar las fechas y despues con el boton buscar llamo la funcion get_mes para que llene la tabla con las fechas ya filtradas y la sigue dejando en blanco :(

Comment: Tendrias que llamar a `self.run_query` de la siguiente forma `self.run_query(query[0], query[1:])` en teoría...

Comment: hice el llamado tal como lo sugeriste y me envió este error `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "S": syntax error` :S en los entrys coloco la fecha como lo tiene en la base de datos ya que me ayudo con el DbBrowser para observar como van entrando los datos...
Entonces esta bien declarada la busqueda con la sentencia between??

Comment: Si, la query en es correcta en principio, te dejo un ejemplo online para que puedas verlo: https://repl.it/@FJSevilla/Sqlite-date-query. La forma que pongo arriba (`self.run_query(query[0], query[1:])`), es para como tienes tu código en la pregunta: `query = ("SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE fecha_de_estudio BETWEEN ? AND ?", self.fecha_i.date(), self.fecha_f.date())`. La idea es que pase la cadena de la query como primer argumento y como segundo la tupla con las fechas : `self.run_query("SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE fecha_de_estudio BETWEEN ? AND ?", (self.fecha_i.date(), self.fecha_f.date()))`

Comment: muchas gracias amigo JFSevilla, voy a tomar tu ejemplo para poder manejarlo y asi ver la manera de ajustarlo con mi programa principal, por lo visto he estado haciendo algo mal :( creo que estoy en una parte muy dificil ya llevo 3 semanas viendo eso jajajaja

Comment: Amigo @JFSevilla, gracias a tu ejemplo, obtuve ya el resultado esperado de hecho tuve que modificar en self.run_query(query) ya que estaba pasando como primer argumento una tupla, cuando debería ser una cadena y procedi a eliminar la **query** dentro de los parentesis y coloqué la sentencia ` "SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE fecha_de_estudio BETWEEN ? AND ?", self.fecha_i.date(), self.fecha_f.date()` y funcionó por completo! agradezco tu tiempo estoy por terminar ya el programa, una pregunta tengo que colocar bien la respuesta abajo para que los compañeros vean cual fué la solucion?